# Pgfplots skips yticks

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to make a graph using pgfplots, where the y-ticks are evenly spaced from 0 to 100, so: 0, 10, 20 etc. But when I create this graph the y-ticks immediately go from 0 to 30, after which they're evenly spaced with a distance of 10 again. How can I make it so the ticks go from 0 to 10 to 20 etc without skipping some ticks? The code I use is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        domain = 0:35,
        range = 0:100,
        xlabel = $t(m)$,
        ylabel = $T(\degree C)$,
        grid=major,
        ytick distance=10,
        legend pos=north west]
\addplot coordinates {
(0, 24)
(0.5, 24.5)
(1, 25)
(1.5, 26.5)
(2, 28)
(2.5, 30)
(3, 33)
(4, 37)
(5, 40.3)
(6, 44)
(7, 48)
(8, 51.8)
(9, 54.2)
(10, 58.9)
(11, 61)
(12, 64)
(13, 66.3)
(14, 69)
(15, 71.1)
(16, 73.4)
(17, 75.8)
(18, 79.5)
(19, 80.6)
(20, 82.1)
(21, 85)
(22, 86.9)
(23, 88.5)
(23.95, 90)
(24.45, 88.5)
(24.95, 87.4)
(25.45, 86.6)
(25.95, 85.6)
(26.45, 84.7)
(26.95, 84)
(27.95, 82.1)
(28.95, 80.6)
(29.95, 79)
(30.95, 78)
(31.95, 76.5)
(32.95, 76.1)
(33.95, 74)
};
\addlegendentry{meetwaardes}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks in advanced for helping!

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document, which begin with `\documentclass{...}`, continue with preamble with loading only  packages necessary for demonstrate your problem, `\begin{document}`, your code fragment and ending with `\end{document}.

Comment: Just add `ymin=0,ymax=100,ytick={0,10,...,100},` to have `0`, `10`, `20`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define `ymin=0` and `ymax=100`, if you like to have complete y axis:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        domain = 0:35,
        range = 0:100,
        xlabel = $t$ (m),
        ylabel = $T$ (\si{\celsius}),
        grid=major,
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        legend pos=north west]
\addplot coordinates {
(0, 24)
(0.5, 24.5)
(1, 25)
(1.5, 26.5)
(2, 28)
(2.5, 30)
(3, 33)
(4, 37)
(5, 40.3)
(6, 44)
(7, 48)
(8, 51.8)
(9, 54.2)
(10, 58.9)
(11, 61)
(12, 64)
(13, 66.3)
(14, 69)
(15, 71.1)
(16, 73.4)
(17, 75.8)
(18, 79.5)
(19, 80.6)
(20, 82.1)
(21, 85)
(22, 86.9)
(23, 88.5)
(23.95, 90)
(24.45, 88.5)
(24.95, 87.4)
(25.45, 86.6)
(25.95, 85.6)
(26.45, 84.7)
(26.95, 84)
(27.95, 82.1)
(28.95, 80.6)
(29.95, 79)
(30.95, 78)
(31.95, 76.5)
(32.95, 76.1)
(33.95, 74)
};
\addlegendentry{meetwaardes}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative solution is use in above MWE `restrict y to domain=0:100,` instead of `ymin=0, ymax=100,`. In this case the result is:

[image]